# React application not running on https

Tags: reactjs, redux

My react-redux application is not running on https. I am using webpack. My Backend API's are running fine on https.

I have changed the URL to https and it's not working however it works on HTTP by default, irrespective whether I write HTTP or https on my code.

Answer (score 0):

The build should be served by a Web Server like nginx or Apache.

You should be able to add SSL to these web servers in order for your app to be served with HTTPS.

There are some free SSL Certificates to be added to your Web Server.

Hope it Helps.